# Should I backup my older questions because they could be deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A few of my older questions have been deleted. I know they existed but I don't remember their titles. Maybe some of them were closed but with very useful answers.

Is there an authority who can do this without notifying me? If not, why I haven't been notified?

Are my deleted questions backed up for some time period (e.g. a year) or should I make the backup myself immediately I have a useful answer?

EDIT (little off topic): [This](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/what-are-some-healthy-filling-snacks) is another question that has been deleted. This is not my question, but has many interesting answers and I have it in my bookmarks if Firefox. I can't read it anymore. Though I found a [copy](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=fitness.stackexchange&question=1373&printer=false&linktohome=true) on stackprinter website which saved it.

EDIT [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101/where-do-you-store-your-code-snippets) interesting question that has dead link.

Comment: *Are my deleted questions backed up for some time period?* Deleted questions are still in the system, but can be viewed by those of us, who has 10k+ reputation.

Comment: Support this feature request: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/158605)

Comment: The users with 10k+ reputation can see the deleted questions. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) for more info.

Comment: @on-nom-nom So, if I will receive 10K reputation in a 5 years I can see my deleted question? It will still be there? What if nobody has 10k reputation? Isn't it too much? Many small SE sites don't have possibility to receive so high reputation.

Comment: @Rachel OK, this is useful.

Comment: If your post received votes, you may be able to find a link to it in your reputation history if you go back far enough and check "show removed posts".

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thanks I can see it. Actually the questions weren't so good but I could be notified. The better question were migrated to gardening and I forgot it. But the feeling of more than one question on that site was right. Actually, there is only a title (not clickable link)

Comment: @xralf The "removed" event is only text, but I think the "upvote" and "downvote" events will be linked if you can go back far enough to find one.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You're right but the links are dead.

Comment: @xralf Post a link to any question you want a copy of [here in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8979/question-recovery-service) and I'll get it for you.

Comment: Just for the record -- I answered your question and it was deleted and I wasn't notified. Think of it like a meta-example: the proof is in the pudding.

Comment: @EvanCarroll That's sad, because there was useful information in question and in the comments.

Comment: @xralf as there always is.

Comment: Vote to Undelete this Post > "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted" might as well say, **"THERE IS NO DEMOCRACY HERE YOU FOOL"**

Comment: @EvanCarroll Paste here a link to the content of your answers and comments after you gain 10000 reputation. It's not deleted, only invisible for users with less than 10000 reputation, so nothing's lost.

Comment: Where was it ever claimed that there is democracy here?

Comment: @CodyGray [StackOverflow about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) says "We don't run StackOverflow. *You* do... We periodically hold democratic moderator elections"

Comment: @xralf: "Where do you store your code snippets?" *On a hard drive like everybody else...* Is that really an example of a **good** question to keep around? StackOverflow is not SurveyMonkey, a forum, Reddit, digg, slashdot, or the internet equivalent of Hoarders.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I was curious about the other possibilities. I clicked on this a link in a blog and it was dead. It should be converted to some wiki but not deleted. The information is then missing not only on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A few of my older questions have been deleted. I know they existed but I don't remember their titles. Maybe some of them were closed but with very useful answers.

If a question has useful answers, it may be closed, but it's not likely to be deleted. Deletion is for content which really contributes nothing useful to the site.

> Is there an authority who can do this without notifying me? If not, why I haven't been notified?

Yes, you are not notified when a question of yours is deleted (as far as I know).

> Are my deleted questions backed up for some time period (e.g. a year) or should I make the backup myself immediately I have a useful answer?

Deletion on Stack Exchange is a "soft deletion" which means the content is really just made invisible to most users, not really deleted. Accordingly there is no need for it to be backed up (beyond the backups that are already done for the whole SE network). Any deleted content can still be seen by moderators and users with over 10000 reputation.

If you need to get access to your deleted content, you might be able to ask a moderator to copy it into a meta post for you.

Comment: Is the reputation 10000 sufficient in one of the SE sites to see deleted questions on all SE sites?

Comment: Privileges are done on a site-by-site basis. So no, having 10k rep on one site does not allow you to see deleted content on other sites.

Comment: So, [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/879/berin-loritsch) is the only man who can see what was deleted here and [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users) only three users can see deleted content. I think somebody deleted it because I wasn't visiting these sites often.

Comment: @xralf I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this yet: the reputation requirements are lower on beta sites. [Only 2000 reputation is required to see deleted posts on Gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), so it's actually 15 users.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I have found the [moderator](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/8/ivo-flipse). How could I contact him? I don't see him in chat. Should I make a facebook or twitter account or is there some message possibility?

Comment: @xralf "I think somebody deleted it because I wasn't visiting these sites often" -- Nope, no way, absolutely not. Posts are **only** delete if they are completely worthless. If that's not the case, did you use a *registered* account? Perhaps you actually have multiple accounts and are not aware of it; they can be merged to recover your content if so. If you do think something shady has happened, there's a contact button at the bottom of every page; use it and carefully explain exactly what you're missing and that you'd like to retrieve it.

Comment: @ChrisS OK, but it's (in my opinion) bad I haven't been notified. The user should have a right to be notified when his question is deleted. I have only one account for all SE sites.

Comment: @xralf I agree, and have put my support into [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/158605)

Answer (score 18):

[David's already given you some good background information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125902/should-i-backup-my-older-questions-because-they-could-be-deleted/125907#125907) here, but I'd like to provide you with a bit of a sanity-check lest you think your questions might be getting deleted out from under you without warning...

- You have **34** deleted questions.
- Of these, **27** were deleted... *By you*.
- Of those remaining, **3** were deleted automatically after being migrated.
- Of the last **4**, all but one were deleted by moderators *after you flagged to ask that they be deleted.*
- The last one was deleted because you cross-posted it on another site.

This is pretty typical. If a moderator needs to go in and delete your posts without your permission, and your account is in good standing otherwise, they'll usually post a comment detailing why first (assuming no one else has already done so). When no reason is given, you can usually assume it's one of [the standard reasons listed in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake and forgot it, but I haven't visited the site for a few months and the deletions are from February. I apologize if this is the case and I forgot about my old requests (which is possible). Anyway, I'm glad I have asked and know the possibilities users have.

Answer (score 9):

You should make a backup of anything you give to a third-party provider.  If a dragon destroyed Stack Exchange tomorrow and your questions/answers went away what would you do? ***What would you DO??***

Comment: +1 for simple, sound advice with a sprinkle of dragons on top

Comment: The dragon should be clever to destroy many servers spread over the world :-) OK. I'm trying to find out how high the risk of data loss is. The dragon has small probability (risk). I can ignore this risk because the loss is not so painful in this case. I sacrifice all my questions if such a dragon will destroy SE.

Comment: I'd look at archive.org

Comment: what if someone were to destroy the world? What would you DO??

Comment: @prusswan I'd throw the mother of all parties before the end :-)